# STM32 option bytes from embeded bootloader

Tags: stm32, bootloader

I'm developing a desktop application which interacts with STM32 embeded bootloader and supports "USART protocol used in the STM32 bootloader" ([AN3155](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/an3155-usart-protocol-used-in-the-stm32-bootloader-stmicroelectronics.pdf)).
STM32 mcu is: STM32U575ZIT6Q

I managed to connect to the embeded bootloader and execute some basic operations (write memory, erase, etc) with no errors.

Problem: I would like to access option bytes with embeded bootloader, but I can't find flash address for them.

From chapter 7.3.1 [RM0456](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/rm0456-stm32u5-series-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf) it is said that option bytes can be accessed only through flash registers:

> -option bytes for user configuration. Unlike user flash memory and system memory,
> it is not mapped to any memory address and can be accessed only through the
> flash register interface.

I'm pretty sure there is must be a way to access it through embeded bootloader,
since in AN3155 "write memory command" can access it.
Also, I can access option bytes with STM32 Cube Programmer.

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: The addresses of the option bytes in flash are in the datasheet (not the reference manual).  However, remember that there are two copies of the option bytes and bad things happen if they don't match.

Comment: The main reason I wanted to get access to it is to "play" with DUAL and SWAP BANK options.

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

In RM0456 there is table "Memory map and peripheral register boundary addresses (continued)" where we can see that FLSAH registers are located in 0x40022000 for my MCU.

FLASH_OPTR register has offset 0x40 hence full address is 0x40022040.
Same address is shown in STM32 Cube Programmer.

[image]